# Finding ALL child controls WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to find all of the controls within a WPF control. I have had a look at a lot of samples and it seems that they all either require a Name to be passed as parameter or simply do not work.

I have existing code but it isn't working properly:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
  if (depObj != null)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
      DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
      if (child != null && child is T)
      {
        yield return (T)child;
      }

      foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
      {
        yield return childOfChild;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For instance it will not get a `DataGrid` within a `TabItem`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use these.

```
 public static List<T> GetLogicalChildCollection<T>(this DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            List<T> logicalCollection = new List<T>();
            GetLogicalChildCollection(parent, logicalCollection);
            return logicalCollection;
        }

 private static void GetLogicalChildCollection<T>(DependencyObject parent, List<T> logicalCollection) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            IEnumerable children = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parent);
            foreach (object child in children)
            {
                if (child is DependencyObject)
                {
                    DependencyObject depChild = child as DependencyObject;
                    if (child is T)
                    {
                        logicalCollection.Add(child as T);
                    }
                    GetLogicalChildCollection(depChild, logicalCollection);
                }
            }
        }
```

You can get child button controls in RootGrid f.e like that:

```
 List<Button> button = RootGrid.GetLogicalChildCollection<Button>();
```

Comment: Logical tree does not contain visuals from control's template. Your code can't find *all* child controls by definition.

Comment: Thanx that worked! It gets my `DataGrid ` unlike my own code!

Comment: @ChrisjanLodewyks Glad to hear it.

Comment: LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren() was the key for me here.

Comment: I've searched all over the web for a solution like this. I tried many things to make this work but everything failed. Till i found this post, everything is working now. THANK YOU!

Comment: Should be noted that the IEnumerable in this code is taken from System.Collections, not from System.Collections.Generic ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17703382/997940))

Comment: You should add a level/rank info, if the Canvas contains another Canvas? Both with some buttons inside.You will get all the buttons at the same level, and this is not the reality. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this Example:

```
public Void HideAllControl()
{ 
           /// casting the content into panel
           Panel mainContainer = (Panel)this.Content;
           /// GetAll UIElement
           UIElementCollection element = mainContainer.Children;
           /// casting the UIElementCollection into List
           List < FrameworkElement> lstElement =    element.Cast<FrameworkElement().ToList();

           /// Geting all Control from list
           var lstControl = lstElement.OfType<Control>();
           foreach (Control contol in lstControl)
           {
               ///Hide all Controls 
               contol.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
           }
}
```