# IEnumerable property without type

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, ienumerable, itemssource

I'm trying to make a property like the official DataGrid.ItemsSource, from MSDN:

```
public IEnumerable ItemsSource { get; set; }
```

This provides the support of any type, in any derived class. With this, I can set something like

```
var list = new List<ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<decimal, bool>>>();
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
```

But when I try to make a property of an IEnumerable without the Type T, exactly as MSDN says, I get an error on VisualStudio:

```
Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments
```

So, what is wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use the non-generic type `System.Collections.IEnumerable`.
(note the different namespace)

Note that in .Net 4.0+, you can use `IEnumerable<object>` instead (due to covariance).