# Visual studio - toggle switch hiding text blocks?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, togglebutton, toggleswitch

I am doing a school project and i can´t figure out how to "hide" some text blocks when the toggle switch is on and the opposite? Developing a windows 8 app. Thanks and btw. How do you make a collection from multiple text blocks(XAML)?

```
private void ToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: By textblocks do you mean, textbox?

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp I think OP talks about https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.aspx, also VS in title possibly indicates need to show/hide pieces of code as shown in [JonH](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29477037/477420) answer.

Comment: It looks like a homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your control structure is fairly flat, you can get by using the `Tag` property on the `TextBox`.  In your XAML, put some distinct value in the `Tag` field for each `TextBox` you want to make toggle-able, like the word 'CanToggle'.  Then you can do something like

```
private void ToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     foreach (Control currentControl in this.Children)
     {
          if (currentControl.Tag == "CanToggle")
               currentControl.Visible = !currentControl.Visible;
     }
}
```

If your control collection is not flat, then you'll have to figure out how to dig recursively through the collection of controls to locate all the `TextBox` that you want to toggle. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875042/finding-all-child-controls-wpf) may help.

Comment: I'm assuming the visual studio reference in the question title is a red herring; i.e., the OP is using Visual Studio to accomplish his task, but that it is not a part of the task.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Main Menu - Edit - Outlining - Toggle All Outlining: Ctrl+M, Ctrl+L

Personally, I use Ctrl+M to "collapse to defininitions" more than anything else though.

Comment: I strongly suspect that OP put VS in title just for fun... But this is reasonable interpretation of the question.

Comment: Based on the code snipped OP posted, this is about hiding controls in code based on an event, not about Visual Studio.